# is it possible to start a div from a first component and end in another component in react js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

suppose I have two components Component A and component B

```
<div class="theme-layout">
    
    <div class="responsive-header">
        <div class="mh-head first Sticky">
            <span class="mh-btns-left">
                <a class="" href="#menu"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></a>
            </span>
            <span class="mh-text">
                <a href="newsfeed.html" title=""><img src="images/logo2.png" alt=""></a>
            </span>
            <span class="mh-btns-right">
                <a class="fa fa-sliders" href="#shoppingbag"></a>
            </span>
        </div>
)
```

and another component B like

```
return (
  <div class="bottombar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span class="copyright"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.templateshub.net">Templates Hub</a></span>
                    <i><img src="images/credit-cards.png" alt=""></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
)
```

Main div is starting from component A and ending in component B how can i split these two component into header and footer in react js.?

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: I got the html design from designer and now need to use these in react and convert these html into react jsx

Comment: probably not a good idea. it would be better to wrap both of your components in that div

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html
 You are probably new to react. I would suggest reading the docs/watching a few courses before getting started.

Comment: @AndreiTătar yes I am and thanks for the suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong you cannot start your main div from component A and ends in component B , In react single component JSX is only valid for these component only, so we can cannot used main div for those two component, and don't forget to self-closed  tag